# Laravel Factories Date FAKER

Tags: laravel, faker

I have the following database, and in table Days I plan to put all the days let´s say, from 01.01.2022 to 31.12.2023. How can I do that with faker?
[image]

My migration is the following:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('days', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->date('date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But I don´t know how to complete the factory...

Comment: Do you need a Factory or a database seeder?

Comment: Add this: `"date" => $this->faker->date("Y-m-d"),` at the `DayFactory::definition()` method and your facctory will work

Answer (score 0):

You mean Seeder, you can create a factory easily, just add the following to your `definition()` method at `DayFactory`

```php
return [
  "name" => $this->faker->date("Y-m-d"),
];
```

Then create a seeder and finally add the following to your `run()` method

```php
$start = now()->startOfYear();
$count = $start->diffInDays(now()->endOfYear());

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  Day::factory([ "date" => $start->copy()->addDays($i) ])->create();
}
```

And you will have from begining to the end of this year.